# Socket.io tutorial not printing connection to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

I don't understand why it won't print "a user connected" when I refresh the page and I was wondering why that is. Below is the index.html file. I am following the get-started tutorial (http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
     }
     body {
        font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
     }
     form {
        background: #000;
        padding: 3px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
     }
     form input {
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 90%;
        margin-right: 0.5%;
     }
     form button {
        width: 9%;
        background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
        border: none;
        padding: 10px;
     }
     #messages {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     }
     #messages li {
        padding: 5px 10px;
     }
     #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #eee;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages">
        <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
    </ul>

    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js">
        var socket = io();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I did that, still doesn't work. Even after restarted server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem lies in this part of your html file:

`<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js">
        var socket = io();
 </script>`

#### You need to load the socket.io library first like so:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

#### Then instantiate the socket.io object:

`<script>
        var socket = io();
</script>`

Comment: Why can't I load the script in the same script where I instantiate the socket.io object?

Comment: Because your script tag has a src attribute it is seen as a 'blocking' script were the code inside of your script tag is being loaded asynchronously. So it's executing the code inside of the tag before the file in the src attribute has been loaded.  To my knowledge it's best practice to keep files and inline scripts in separate tags.